# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module simpleModule.ko: Operation not permitted

Tags: kernel, makefile

I'm a beginner learning about linux kernel. I tried to insert a simple module but encountered the following error.

```
sudo insmod simpleModule.ko
[sudo] password: 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module simpleModule.ko: Operation not permitted
```

Contents of my simpleModule.c file:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int simple_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading module\n");
    return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing module\n");  
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
```

My Makefile:

```
obj-m +=simpleModule.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Please help me in understanding this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to UEFI Secure Boot? See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/178692

Comment: Isn't there any other way?

Comment: To complement @steeldriver comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546126/insmod-error-could-not-insert-module-helloworld-ko-operation-not-permitted